# Why am I getting 0x from provider.getCode?

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

I've deployed my contract on the correct network (rinkeby) as seen [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x1fc7fe607ba2481ff492814c27943dedb8cba0ce). I've also connected my wallet address to the dApp selecting the correct network. I have run `npx hardhat compile` to update my contract artifact. However, when I try to run `provider.getCode(contractAddress)`, it returns with `0x`, and I can't figure out why.

```js
const contractAddress = '0x1Fc7Fe607BA2481Ff492814C27943dEdB8cBA0cE'
const provider = await web3Modal.connect()
const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(provider)
console.log(await web3Provider.getCode(contractAddress)) // returns 0x
```

Comment: 0x is null.  It is returning null, check to documentation for what that means

Answer (score 1):

Because it is [address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUZCq.png), the address will return 0x, it is also possible that your node is wrong and not on the right chain . Because the address I saw on the Goerli testnet is the contract, and the link you provided is the Rinkeby testnet. :)